# How to access MongoDB outside of vagrant?

Tags: mongodb, ssh, vagrant, port, virtualbox

I have tried to connect to vagrant MongoDB outside of vagrant. However, every time failed.
I have tried as followings.

Change `/etc/mongodb.conf` as
`bind = 0.0.0.0`
`port = 27017`
`sudo service mongodb restart`

MongoDB shell version v3.6.3

vagrant file like this

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 1206

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5050, host: 5050

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017

Comment: did you add authentication ?

Comment: Yes, I have done this.

Comment: Show the full Vagrantfile (are you using static ip ?) how do u try to access mongo ?

Comment: Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "learntio/localdev"
  config.vm.box_version = "0.0.1"
  config.ssh.insert_key = true
  config.ssh.username = 'root'
  config.ssh.password = 'forever126'  

   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 1206
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5050, host: 5050
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "4096"
  end
end

Comment: Jupiter, you may want to add your config file as code section in your initial question (indent code by four spaces, line by line for multi-line code sections). Right now, it is a bit hard to read.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for all your comment. I resolve this. This is my issue. Sorry.